# How to enable lookup filter

Tags: lookup, master-detail, lookup-filter

I'm trying to find a way to add filter to a lookup popup window but I'm unable to find how to do that.

I have custom object which has master/detail relationship and what I want that when the user clicks magnifier the popup window should filter the data before it displays.

PS: I have enabled the enhanced search on the custom object but still unable to create filter.

Screen shot:

[image]

Comment: You need to add a filter in field settings https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=fields_lookup_filters_defining.htm